# HTML form input changed but then changed back to original value

Tags: javascript, jquery

So this was hard to search on, read on you'll see why.

This is my goal - detect if a form field has changed so i can enable the "Save" button.  Ok, so this is super easy.  Here's the rub.  If the user then changes the input back to the ORIGINAL value when the form loaded I want to disable the save button again.

Quick example;

- Page loads - input contains the value "red"
- User changes it to "blue"
- `script detects change from original value, enable the save button`
- User then decides he liked "red" so changes the input back to "red"
- `script sees the change is same as original value, disable the save button`

I know this may be a bit anal.  But my clients don't get why the form still needs saved if the input is back to the beginning value.

Of course the whole thing then needs to work with many inputs.

Comment: What have you tried? SO isn't a code writing service.

Comment: @mike. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have some `onChange` callback that you've registered on the `change' event for input fields. In that callback you'd want to be able to check if the new value has gone back to the original value. (If so, you'd want to disable the save button again). What is missing is some reference to the original value.

So when do you first know what the initial value is? I'm guessing you are, at some point, populating the input field with previously saved data. At that time, you had the information about what the "original" value was.

Now you want to have a specialized `onChange` callback for each of the input fields, where each of these callbacks would have access to the original value.

One way you could do that is using higher order functions. A function returning a new function. How would that work?

```
function createOnChangeCallback(originalValue) {
   // returning a function!
   return function(changeEvent) {
      // this is the callback that will run for one
      // of the input elements. Note that the "originalValue"
      // is in scope
      const newValue = changeEvent.target.value;
      const hasGoneBackToOriginalValue = newValue == originalValue;
      if(hasGoneBackToOriginalValue) {
         // disable the submit button
      }
   }
};
```

Then, when you are populating a specific field, you would do something like

```
// get a reference to the input element
const $myInput = $('#myInput');
// give the input field it's first value ("populate")
$myInput.val(originalValue);
// create a specialized callback with access to the original value
$myInput.click( createOnChangeCallback(originalValue) )
```

Answer (score 0):

A little more background.  The app built using the .Net and MVC technology.

The primary view page where most action is happening has a table with a page 
of job request records. Each record has an "Edit" link like this.

```
<a href="/Job/_JobEdit?id=10079" class="btnJobEdit">Edit</a>
```

I use jquery to catch events at the document level because the table is loaded and rendered dynamically using the DataTables.net library.

Here's how I catch the "Click" event of the ".btnJobEdit" links (there will be one for each row of the jobs table).
And also the "Change" and "Submit" events of the "#frmJobEdit", this form does not exist until the above "Edit" link is clicked.

```
$(document)
  .on('click', '.btnEditJob', event_click_btnEditJob)
  .on('change', '#frmJobEdit', function () {
    // .valid() is a jQuery validation library
    $(this).find(':submit').attr('disabled', !$(this).valid()); 
    $(this).find(':reset').attr('disabled', false);
  })
  .on('submit', '#frmJobEdit', event_submit_frmJobEdit)
```

**Now we have the inital page loaded.**

When a user clicks the "Edit" button for a record the function event_click_btnEditJob() runs.

Heres that simple function

```
function event_click_btnEditJob() {
  event.preventDefault();

  $.get($(this).attr('href'), function (response) { 
    // the response will be a full html form returned as a partial view 
    // by the _JobEdit method of the JobController

    // I then set this into a BootStrap modal dialog and show the modal
    $('#modal_JobEdit .modal-body')
      .html(response)
      .modal('show') 
  }); 
}
```

When the user clicks the "Save Changes" button the function event_submit_frmJobEdit handles the submit again thru ajax call to the JobController which again returns a partial view with the form and the newly changed data ready for another edit as well as now there is a message indication the success or fail of the submit action.

This existing process is, clean, stable and simple.  Introducing this requirement of toggling the "Save" button based on user edits is undesirable from the development perspective.  And at this time the customer representatives to this project have agreed.  "**Train the users!**"

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$("#your-client-form").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); //prevents for reloading the page.
});
```

Comment: Can you explain how this would (visibly) disable the save-button based on the value of the input, before the button is pressed?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a full example of doing something similar to what you want to do.

```js
// Retrieves the initial state of the form as a JSON object
// data-field-name determines the JSON field name
const getForm = () => {
  return $("#my-form");
};

const getFormState = (form) => {
  let originalFormState = {};
  form.children(":input").each(function() {
    const fieldName = $(this).data("fieldName");
    const fieldValue = $(this).val();
    if (fieldName) {
      originalFormState[fieldName] = fieldValue;
    }
  });
  return originalFormState;
};

const setSubmitButtonState = (form, isChanged) => {
  form.children("#submit-form").prop("disabled", isChanged);
};

const checkAndHandleFormState = (form, originalFormState) => {
  const currentFormState = getFormState(form);
  let isChanged = false;
  for (const field of Object.keys(originalFormState)) {
    if (originalFormState[field] !== currentFormState[field]) {
      isChanged = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  setSubmitButtonState(form, isChanged);
};

const addListenersToFormInputFields = (form, originalFormState) => {
  form.children(":input").each(function() {
    if ($(this).data("fieldName")) {
      $(this).change(function() {
        const fieldName = $(this).data("fieldName");
        const fieldValue = $(this).val();
        checkAndHandleFormState(getForm(), originalFormState);
      });
    }
  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  const form = getForm();
  addListenersToFormInputFields(form, getFormState(form));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="my-form">
  <input id="name" data-field-name="name" type="text" value="John" />
  <input id="age" data-field-name="age" type="text" value="12" />
  <input id="submit-form" type="submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry - It took me a while to get back to this.  First thanks for the reply's and samples.  I haven't the time to evaluate the responses yet, but they look very promising.  For now this is low priority. as core functionality is top.